# Django jQuery File Upload files not being posted

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to implement [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) with Django 1.10. I read through the wiki and other attempts but I want to use a different approach than the ones listed in the wiki so I cannot reuse their implementation. My setup is they select the file(s), fill in some other data, then submit the form. The post data goes to a view that handles chunked uploads and creates a tracker object.

The files are being recognized when I add them (being added to the table showing files), but they are not making it to the view. The html/view are linked but when I check the post data in the view, the file list is empty.

HTML:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
        <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/no_javascript/"></noscript>

        <div class="row">
            <input type="file" id="files_picker" name="files[]" multiple class="input_hidden">
            <div class="btn btn-success" onclick="clickAdd()">
                <span>Add Files</span>
            </div>

            <!-- The loading indicator is shown during file processing -->
            <span class="fileupload-loading"></span>
        </div>

        <!-- The global progress state -->
        <div class="fileupload-progress fade">
            <!-- The global progress bar -->
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0;"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- The extended global progress state -->
            <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>

        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table role="presentation" class="alternating-table">
            <tbody class="files"></tbody>
        </table>

        // other inputs

        <div class="row">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="upload_submit" onclick="clickStarts();">
                <span>Start Upload</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Included js:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/upload/jquery.ui.widget.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/upload/tmpl.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/upload/load-image.all.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/upload/canvas-to-blob.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/upload/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/upload/jquery.iframe-transport.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/upload/jquery.fileupload.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/upload/jquery.fileupload-process.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/upload/jquery.fileupload-image.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/upload/jquery.fileupload-audio.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/upload/jquery.fileupload-video.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/upload/jquery.fileupload-validate.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/upload/jquery.fileupload-ui.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/upload/fileupload-main.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/upload/locale.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/upload/custom-upload.js' %}"></script>
```

fileupload-main.js:

```
$(function () {
'use strict';

// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
$('#fileupload').fileupload({});

// Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
$('#fileupload').fileupload(
    'option',
    'redirect',
    window.location.href.replace(
        /\/[^\/]*$/,
        '/cors/result.html?%s'
    )
);

// Load existing files:
$('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
$.ajax({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
    dataType: 'json',
    context: $('#fileupload')[0]
}).always(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
}).done(function (result) {
    $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
        .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
});
});
```

custom-upload.js:

```
//simulate click on file input button
    function clickAdd() {
        $('#files_picker').click();
    }

    $(function () {
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            uploadTemplateId: 'template-upload',
            downloadTemplateId: 'template-download'
        });
    });

    function clickStarts() {
        $("#fileupload").validate();
        if ($("#fileupload").valid()) {
            $('.start').click();
            $('#fileupload').fileupload('send', {files: filesList});
        }
    }
```

view:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        files = request.FILES.getlist('files')
        for f in files:
            handle_uploaded_file(f)

            # create upload object
            Upload(name=f.name, file=f, date=datetime.now().date(), ...).save()

    return render(request, 'upload.html', {})


class UploadDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Upload

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.object.delete()
        response = JSONResponse(True, mimetype=response_mimetype(request))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
       return response


class UploadListView(ListView):
    model = Upload

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        files = [serialize(p) for p in self.get_queryset()]
        data = {'files': files}
        response = JSONResponse(data, mimetype=response_mimetype(self.request))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
        return response


def handle_uploaded_file(f):
"""
Handles uploaded files
Reads in chunks and sends them off to their destination
"""
    import os

    # write file to uploads folder
    path = os.path.join('/uploads/', f.name)
    with open(path, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
           destination.write(chunk)
```

upload model:

```
class Upload(models.Model):

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Upload"
    verbose_name_plural = "Uploads"

# name of file
name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)

# file
file = models.FileField(upload_to="/uploads")

# Date uploaded
date = models.DateField('Date Uploaded', default=None)

# others

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.file.delete(False)
    super(Upload, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```